# Impliment chat in flutter without using Firebase

Tags: node.js, flutter, sockets, chat

I have a feature request for my app that needs chat functionality.
What are the ways this can be achieved. Backend is in nodejs.

Tried socket.io but let's just say socket.io and flutter don't like each other.

I **don't** want to use Firebase or any 3rd party service

Comment: create a websocket

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise you to use node.js and socket.io, if you don't want to use third parties to help you, I will give you a [link to a playlist from YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLtIU0BH0pkKovuEaNsrGE_Xd5Tz3m1zeC), where a person from 0 developed chat application. He introduced a huge amount of functionality from scrap there, so just follow his example and you will overcome any difficulties!